# Size Mismatch using pytorch when trying to train data

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, linear-regression, tensor

I am really new to pytorch and just trying to use my own dataset to do a simple Linear Regression Model. I am only using the numbers values as inputs, too.

[image: The CSV File I Imported]

I have imported the data from the CSV

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('mlb_games_overview.csv')
```

I have split the data into four parts X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test

```
X = dataset.drop(['date', 'team', 'runs', 'win'], 1)
y = dataset['win']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=True)
```

I have converted the data to pytorch tensors

```
X_train = torch.from_numpy(np.array(X_train))
X_test = torch.from_numpy(np.array(X_test))
y_train = torch.from_numpy(np.array(y_train))
y_test = torch.from_numpy(np.array(y_test))
```

I have created a LinearRegressionModel

```
class LinearRegressionModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LinearRegressionModel, self).__init__()
        self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(1, 1)
    def forward(self, x):
        y_pred = self.linear(x)
        return y_pred
```

I have initialized the optimizer and the loss function

```
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
```

Now when I start to train the data I get the runtime error mismatch

```
EPOCHS = 500
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    pred_y = model(X_train) # RUNTIME ERROR HERE
    loss = criterion(pred_y, y_train)
    optimizer.zero_grad() # zero out gradients to update parameters correctly
    loss.backward() # backpropagation
    optimizer.step() # update weights
    print('epoch {}, loss {}'. format(epoch, loss.data[0]))
```

Error Log:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-c0474231d515> in <module>
  1 EPOCHS = 500
  2 for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
----> 3     pred_y = model(X_train)
  4     loss = criterion(pred_y, y_train)
  5     optimizer.zero_grad() # zero out gradients to update parameters correctly
RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [3540 x 8], m2: [1 x 1] at 
C:\w\1\s\windows\pytorch\aten\src\TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:752
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Linear Regression model, you have:

```
self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(1, 1)
```

But your training data (`X_train`) shape is `3540 x 8` which means you have 8 features representing each input example. So, you should define the linear layer as follows.

```
self.linear = torch.nn.Linear(8, 1)
```

A [linear layer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=linear#torch.nn.Linear) in PyTorch has parameters, `W` and `b`. If you set the `in_features` to 8 and `out_features` to 1, then the shape of the `W` matrix will be `1 x 8` and the length of `b` vector will be 1.

Since your training data shape is `3540 x 8`, you can perform the following operation.

```
linear_out = X_train W_T + b
```

I hope it clarifies your confusion.